# Cambiar valor de un input desde javascript según la edad

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito que el valor del `<input>` según la edad del usuario, seria así: cuando se ponga la fecha de nacimiento validar si cumple con la edad y le asigna si es Juvenil o Prejuvenil.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="birth_date" class="form-control-label">
        FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DEL PARTICIPANTE
    </label>                                                                                             
        <input type="date" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" required class="form-control">
</div>
```

y acá se debe colocar el resultado

```
<div class="col-4" id="group_etary">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="age_group" class="form-control-label">
        GRUPO ETARIO
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="age_group" id="age_group" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
```

Éste es mi código, pero no sé si está bien escrito. He buscado en varias partes y no lo logro aún.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function comprobar()
    {
       var birth_date= document.birth_date.value;

       if (birth_date>= 5 && birth_date <= 12)
       {
            $('#age_group').val('PREJUVENIL');
          // alert("Si tienes entre 5 y 12 años, perteneces a el grupo prejuvenil.");
          return false;
       }

       if (birth_date>= 13 && birth_date <= 17)
       {
            $('#age_group').val('JUVENIL');
          // alert("Si tienes entre 13 y 17 años, perteneces a el grupo juvenil.");
          return false;
       }

       return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No veo la llamada a la función `comprobar()` ¿Cuando la llamas? Por otro lado, concretar más el comportamiento erróneo que te sucede facilitará las cosas a quien trate de ayudarte.

Comment: A primera vista no creo que debiera funcionar ese `var birth_date= document.birth_date.value;`. Quizá deberías usar `var birth_date= document.getElementById('birth_date').value;`. Además, al ser de tipo "fecha" (`type="date"`) su valor será de la forma `AAAA-MM-DD` y no un número tal cual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El principal problema que veo es que `document.birth_date.value` puede no contener la información que estás buscando. Quizá deberías usar en su lugar
[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
var birth_date = document.getElementById('birth_date').value;
```

Haciendo uso de jQuery se puede simplificar a:

```
var birth_date = $('#birth_date').val();
```

Además, el campo del formulario, al ser de tipo "fecha" (`type="date"`), su valor será de la forma `AAAA-MM-DD` y no un número tal cual, por lo que debes cambiar las comprobaciones numéricas a comprobaciones basadas en texto:

```js
function comprobar()
{
   var birth_date = $('#birth_date').val();
   console.log('Fecha:', birth_date);

   /* Fechas en las que se cumplen 5, 12 y 17 años según fecha base */
   if (birth_date>= '2007-01-01' && birth_date <= '2014-12-31') {
      $('#age_group').val('PREJUVENIL');
      alert("Si tienes entre 5 y 12 años, perteneces a el grupo prejuvenil.");
      return false;
   } else if (birth_date>= '2002-01-01' && birth_date <= '2006-12-31') {
      $('#age_group').val('JUVENIL');
      alert("Si tienes entre 13 y 17 años, perteneces a el grupo juvenil.");
      return false;
   } else {
      $('#age_group').val('NINGUNO');
      alert("Fecha fuera de rango.");
   }

   return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birth_date" class="form-control-label">
        FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DEL PARTICIPANTE
    </label>
        <input type="date" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" required class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-4" id="group_etary">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="age_group" class="form-control-label">
        GRUPO ETARIO
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="age_group" id="age_group" class="form-control">
</div>

<button onclick="comprobar()">Pulsa aquí para comprobar la fecha</button>
```

---

Además, quizá sería mejor implementar una función que calcule la edad basado en una fecha base (a partir de la cual se cuenta la edad de inscripción) y la fecha de nacimiento del jugador:

```js
/* Ésta es la fecha efectiva, por ejemplo, desde la que se calcula la edad */
let fecha_base = new Date('2019-08-01');

function comprobar()
{
   var birth_date = new Date($('#birth_date').val());

   /* Calculamos la edad restando los años: */
   let edad = fecha_base.getFullYear() - birth_date.getFullYear();
   /* Hacemos el corte de mes y día del año en curso */
   birth_date.setFullYear(fecha_base.getFullYear());
   if (fecha_base.getTime() < birth_date.getTime()) {
      /* Si aún no hemos llegado a la fecha de cumpleaños restamos un año */
      edad--;
   }
   console.log('Edad:', edad);

   /* Ahora podemos hacer la comparación con la edad calculada */
   if (edad >= 5 && edad <= 12) {
      $('#age_group').val('PREJUVENIL');
      alert("Si tienes entre 5 y 12 años, perteneces a el grupo prejuvenil.");
      return false;
   } else if (edad >= 13 && edad <= 17) {
      $('#age_group').val('JUVENIL');
      alert("Si tienes entre 13 y 17 años, perteneces a el grupo juvenil.");
      return false;
   } else {
      $('#age_group').val('NINGUNO');
      alert("Edad fuera de rango.");
   }

   return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birth_date" class="form-control-label">
        FECHA DE NACIMIENTO DEL PARTICIPANTE
    </label>
        <input type="date" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" required class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-4" id="group_etary">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="age_group" class="form-control-label">
        GRUPO ETARIO
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="age_group" id="age_group" class="form-control">
</div>

<button onclick="comprobar()">Pulsa aquí para comprobar la fecha</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono...